# Appengine making a scripted static route active in a non scripted static route domain

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In appengine I have mapped `'/'` directory for static folder editing my`app.yaml`. Now the problem it raised is that it can't recognize my other routes (for eg: `/blog/.json`) which I am configuring via my python script. If both of the route were scripted in python then moving a route up and down could have solved this problem but here apparently I can't do that. So what can be done?

main.py

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blog/.json', jsonBlog)], false)
```

app.yaml

```
- url: /
  static_dir: html5
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

before

```
- url: /
  static_dir: html5
```

will solve the problem. First of it will check scripted directory then it will check scripted mapped folders.